# What is the distance to use for Bag of Features similarity?

Tags: image-processing, vector, computer-vision, cluster-computing, distance

I have a set of images `img1`, `img2`, ... , `imgn`.

For each one of them, I've created a vector in `200` dimensions following the [Bag of Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) model, `vc1`, `vc2`, ..., `vcn`, respectively.

Now I want to measure the distance between two vectors in order to measure image similarity. Which distance should I use to measure the distance between two vectors `vci`, `vcj`? I've read somewhere (don't remember why) that chi-square is a common distance for this purpose, but I'm not sure about it.

**Note:** I know that is impractical since the high dimensionality of each vector, in fact this is just to understand which [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) strategy to use (based on the distance vector chosen).